# Bash script how to check if remote file contains a specific string using ssh

Tags: bash

Helo,

I know how to check a local file.

```
if grep -q ExampleString "$File"; then
  Do Action # SomeString was found
fi
```

but how to check remote file, and if string exist goto script action?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the command with ssh in front of it:

```
if ssh user@remote grep -q ExampleString "$File"; then
```

The `"$File"` must be a path accessible on the `remote` site.

Answer (score 0):

If used to call an executable, `ssh` will return the return code of what it calls, so try something like:

```
if ssh remote_host grep -q ExampleString "$File"; then
  Do Action # SomeString was found
fi
```

Note the `$File` variable is local, but it will look for the file on the remote system.